# How to add Info Box in Bing map Controll?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a Bing map Controll on my form and this bing map contains so many pushpins.

When I click on pushpin at that time i want to show an info box.

So how can I add this info box?

please see bellow image.i have to requery this type of info box.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code. All you have to do is attach a Tap event to the pushpin

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitPage();
    }

    private void InitPage()
    {
        testMap.Center = new GeoCoordinate(42,42);
        testMap.ZoomLevel = 10;

        MapLayer pushPinLayer = new MapLayer();
        testMap.Children.Add(pushPinLayer);

        Pushpin pushpin = new Pushpin();

        pushpin.Tap += new EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>(pushpin_Tap);

        pushpin.Content = "SAMPLE";
        pushPinLayer.AddChild(pushpin, new GeoCoordinate(42, 42));

    }

    void pushpin_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You Clicked here");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are right Bragboy.But i want info box not a message box because i have multiple pushpin.And this all pushpin are auto played so message box is not possible.And info box is not possible in wp7? please help me and give ans as soon as possible.

Comment: @Mansinh: What do you mean by Info Box ? take a look here for various prompts supported by the famous coding4fun library for windows phone - http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/ (Sroll to bottom to see the screenshots)

Comment: :please see image which i uploaded.Than give me replay

Comment: @Mansinh: the screenshot you have shown looks like custom overlay element on the map which is very much doable. The screenshot you have shown seems not like Windows Mobile. Can you tell me the exact reason on why you want that so that I can suggest a cleaner solution.

Comment: :actualy i have a bing map controll in this controll i have three button Play,Replay and Info box.when i click on play button at that time all Pushpin button play on some interval.Now i click on info box than it also play but with some information like address,letitude logngitude,ete.exatly like uper screen shots so how can i add this box?.

Answer (score 0):

yes i got what are you saying 
you just put image button over all the geocoordination 
from that you replace the pushpin in place of image buton when any button is press
and dynamically change the content of pushpin in every points